# Sort list by occurrence and alphabetic order

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to put a sentence on a list and then sort the list by the occurrence of the word on the list, and if necessary when 2 words occurre the same amount of times, by alphabetic order. I wrote this code :

```
def frequencia(texto):
    pals = texto.split()
    m = sorted(pals,key=pals.count,reverse=True)
    return m
```

The problem is it repeats the words and doesn't apply the alphabetic order.
On the sentence "I am a guy and I am hungry", the output should be ['am','I','a','guy','hungry']

Comment: The easiest way is probably sort twice, first alphabetically and second by count. Python sorts are stable so once an order is established that order will be retained in any subsequent sort where the keys are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sentence = 'I am a guy and I am hungry'

words = sentence.split(' ')
sortedwords = sorted(set(words), key=lambda x: (-words.count(x), x.lower()))
#  ['am', 'I', 'a', 'and', 'guy', 'hungry']
```

Use `set` to get the unique words in the input.  Then, sort them with a `tuple` with priority given to the highest number of appearances (with a negative count, the most frequent have most negative values and are sorted first) followed by alphabetical order (using `lower()` to make uppercase and lowercase equivalent).